# Pass promise through a cascade of functions "tailing" off from the tip of "thens"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

The situation is as follows:
A button is pushed by the user which fires an event handler consisting of 4 functions. One of these functions does some async job and then enters a cascade of synchronous and (depending on the usecase) asynchronous functions. The code looks roughly like this:

```js
$('#someButton').Click(function(){
handler();
})

async function handler(){
syncFunction1();
syncFunction2();
await asyncFunction3();
syncFunction4();
}

 function asyncFunction3(){

  $.post('someUrl',{
  //nothing to transmit
  }).then((jsonString) => {
  parseJSONtoObject(jsonString)
  })

}

function parseJSONtoObject(data){
//some Code for Conversion
callCascadeOfFunctions();
}

function callCascadeOfFunctions(){
//some Code which calls other functions
//which call other functions
//and so on
   
//here is some illustration of what "callCascadeOfFunctions()" does:
//some code
cascadeStep1();
}

   function  cascadeStep1(){
      if(X){
      cascadeStep2A
      }else{
      cascadeStep2B 
      }

} 
//this continues, sometimes the cascade splits, sometimes not.
//at some point we have another AJAX, coming in like this

function cascadeStepN(){
//some code
await sideCascadeWithAJAX
//some code, leading deeper into the cascade where only synchronous
//operations happen
}
}
```

Now, what's very important is that `handler()` waits for the `asyncFunction3()` cascade to finish before it continues.

In another case, I already returned a promise from the depths of a cascade of functions. However, this code looked more like this:

```js
function foo(){
//some code
await someFunctionCascade();
//call to other functions
}

function someFunctionCascade(){
//call to another synchronous function which calls another function etc..
//at the end of the cascade a function does jquery AJAX which creates a promise
//which is returned all the way up through the cascade to the original call
//inside foo()
 }
```

But this time its a bit more tricky, because the cascade contains both synchronous and asynchronous parts. It starts with the AJAX, enters a cascade of synchronous functions which at some point call an asynchronous function and wait for it to finish, and THEN continues through some synchronous functions to its end.

Do I really need to chain all of this into "thens" or can I circumvent this by returning the promises from the asynchronous all the way up to the original call?
And if so, would this "combination" of a then-structure with the passing up of promises through the synchronous sections work, or is it impossible this way?

Comment: removed the redundant "async" :=)

Comment: Do you want to return anything from these methods? If the answer is no, then the fact that some is async and some isn't is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: no, I definitely don't want to return anything from there. It's only about timing.

EDIT: I edited in some illustration of the processes inside the cascade of functions.

Comment: One of the main things happening in this code is setting some HTML elements to certain values (mainly dropdown menu options). 
The thing is, this website was designed to take the values inside these elements to make a reservation.
The functionality before us has the job to automatically set some values for reservation. You hit the button "make reservation for my favorite workstation" and then the respective menu elements are set accordingly and THEN these values are fetched by the script and used for the call to the database where your reservation is registered. I know, its definitely bad.

Comment: @Liam it's not irrelevant if functions have side-effects, or if they throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

- `cascadeStep1` needs to return the result from `cascadeStep2A` and `cascadeStep2B`. Since all of these are `async` functions they will return a promise.
- `callCascadeOfFunctions` needs to return the result of `casecadeStep1`.

Basically, once you work with `async` functions or functions that do 'things' with promises, they need to all return a promise. As long as everything returns a promise that resolves when their inner operation is complete, `await` can behave correctly.

Comment: Can you please not edit my answer without at least pinging me

Comment: @Liam your version is objectively worse. I do a lot of edits to improve questions and answers, and stack overflow doesn't require permission, just reputation. I don't think I vandalized it

Comment: That said, I will leave it as is though, because an edit war is a bit pointless. Learn how await and promises work together. Your current version doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar for promises, there is no better. They do the same thing in a slightly different way. I'm perfectly au fait with how they work, ta.

Comment: @Liam you're totally right, but it's weird to mix them. It's like using `var` and `let` in the same function. Pick one and stick by it ;)

Comment: Or pick whichever one makes the code easier to read in that instance. There is no practical reason not to mix them.

Comment: @Liam If you think your version is easier to understand, definitely stick by it then! Can't argue taste I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

> synchronous functions which at some point call an asynchronous function and wait for it to finish

By that moment, the "synchronous function" is no longer synchronous. It's asynchronous and should return a promise (for a result value or for `undefined`). It can do that either by returning the promise that the asynchronous call returns, by using `then` on that promise if it wants to do something else after the async call, or by `await`ing the promise.